# svgexport renders font properly on Mac OS X (10.10.3) but not on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu, svg, fonts, phantomjs

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" 
  xml:space="preserve"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="600px" viewbox="0 0 600 600">
<style type="text/css" >
    <![CDATA[

      @font-face {
        font-family: uGillSansLocal;
        src: local('Gill Sans');
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: uGillSansURL;
        src: url('./GillSans.ttf');
      }

    ]]>
</style>
<rect id="Border" x="0" y="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF" width="600" height="600"/>
<text x="100" y="30" font-size="32px" font-family="uGillSansLocal">
    <tspan>uGillSans local</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP[]|</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM&lt;>?</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">1234567890-=!@#$%^&amp;s*()_+</tspan>
</text>
<text x="100" y="300" font-size="32px" font-family="uGillSansURL">
    <tspan>uGillSans url</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP[]|</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM&lt;>?</tspan>
    <tspan x="100" dy="40">1234567890-=!@#$%^&amp;s*()_+</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

This is an SVG file. In ubuntu the rendering looks like this: [image: rendering in ubuntu]. Some characters are rendered wrongly.

However in Mac OS X the rendering like this: [image: rendering in mac os x]. I used [svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport) to render both.

From what I understand, svgexport uses PhantomJS to render SVG. I suspect this is not a problem in PhantomJS, but rather some missing library for font rasterization in Ubuntu.

FYI, Both systems have already the required font installed. Both have latest version of svgexport. How should I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Edit: I've installed libfreetype6 and fontconfig on Ubuntu. Still doesn't work. However, the SVG looks okay on Chrome on both systems.

Comment: Have you done anything to try and diagnose the problem?  For instance, have you tried viewing the SVG file in Chome on Ubuntu (to see if the font renders okay there)?

Comment: on Chrome everything's fine. I've installed libfreetype6 and fontconfig on Ubuntu. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

for me it works like that:

```css
@font-face {
          font-family:'FreeSans';
          src: url('http://localhost/fonts/FreeSans.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
```

Notice that there's a format attached. Maybe it's that?